# Latest Actions in PHP?

Tags: php, sql, join

If you go to http://www.foxnews.com, and scroll down a little you would see the box "LATEST NEWS".

Now I want to do something like that, but with modification.

I have 3 queries, that get out information from 3 tables. But this doesn't give me the "latest news", because it's 3 separate queries.

Now I want to make a box, (I can do this in css), that displays the latest column of those 3 tables, 
sorted by dato DESC.

These are the tables:

Tablename: **Member_meetups**

Column to show: meetup

Table: **member_film**

Column to show: navn

Table: **member_tutorials**

Column to show: title

Sort by dato.. 
All these tables have the column "dato" too, so I want to sort out from dato DESC..

And in that way that would be latest actions from those 3 tables..

FOR EXAMPLE it would show like this:
*Latest Actions:*
I love Meetups - 23:11:02 - 01/01/01 (a column in member_meetups)
I love tutorials - 23:10:00 - 01/01/01 (a column in member_tutorials)
I love tutorials first - 22:59:00 01/01/01 (a column in member_tutorials)
I hate movies! - 22:42:00 01/01/01 (a column in member_film)

**and so on.. as you see sorting by DATO, shows the last column's title+dato in the 3 tables.**

Questions please comment, and please answer with not so hard English, as you may hear, I'm not English myself.
Thank you

My question is: How to do this?

Comment: Why do people vote close please tell me whats wrong and ill come with more details if i can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `UNION`.  Here's a sample query:

```
SELECT meetup AS text, dato FROM Member_meetups UNION
SELECT navn AS text, dato FROM member_film UNION
SELECT title AS text, dato FROM member_tutorials
ORDER BY dato DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

I only selected the columns you indicated; if you're going to need more columns from each table then alter the query as you need to.  Just make sure you line up the column names using the `AS` function as needed to normalize the data.

You should think about caching this data; this can often be quite a slow query.

**Edit to answer question in comments:**

It's not entirely clear to me how you want it to work, and it's difficult to write a full query without your DB's schema, but here's the gist:

```
SELECT m.meetup AS text, m.dato FROM Member_meetups m
INNER JOIN member_battles b
ON m.battle=b.id
WHERE b.fighter1=$pUsername OR b.fighter2=$pUsername UNION
SELECT navn AS text, dato FROM member_film UNION
SELECT title AS text, dato FROM member_tutorials
ORDER BY dato DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Again, that's very rough because I don't know your DB's schema or quite understand what you're wanting the query to do.  If you need more specific help, I'd suggest either editing your question or starting a new one.  It's very difficult to work through these types of things with comments.

Comment: but how should i echo the query then? you know <? echo...?

Comment: The results will be a table with two columns, text and dato, with the contents of all 3 tables combined, and you can loop through it just like if it was returning a single table.

If you're using MySQL procedurally:
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    echo $row['text'] . ' - ' . $row['dato'];
}

Comment: Hello thank you this works perfectly!! So if i need more columns i should do e.g : SELECT meetup AS text, battle AS text, dato FROM member_meetups ?

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to rename two columns from the same table as "text".  I'm not sure what the "battle" column holds, but instead of "AS text", use "AS <a relevant name>", then if you have a similar column in your other tables, use the same "AS <a relevant name>" statement to match them up and you'll end up with a results table with 3 columns: text, <a relevant name>, and dato.

Comment: Hello. I just to know this because i want to SELECT either "fighter2" or "fighter1" which contains = $pUsername in member_battles. Can i do this in this query or would it be too difficult.. Hope im not asking too much

Comment: Edited to attempt to answer your question, though it's a little unclear to me.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually ask a question from what I can gather.

But I shall try to answer your *question* as best as I can.

---

You should use mySQL join. (I'm assuming you are using mySQL).

You can then do what you want in a single query. If you provide more information on your DB schema then it will be possible to construct the exact query for you.

Comment: Sorry i did never actually write a question. But i am using me of mysql and php, and im new with this, so what/where can i get the Database schema?

Comment: Just explain the tables more. Edit your question above.